# Probability of actually being sick after 3 positive tests? (Bayes problem?)

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

I was given the following problem:

The probability of being sick is $0.05$. Probability of a test detecting sickness when you're truly sick is $0.8$. Probability of detecting sickness when you're not sick is $0.01$. If you take 3 consecutive tests, and they all are positive, what is the actual probability of you being sick?

I think this is a Bayes Rule problem. Let $S$ denote that you're truly sick and $S^c$ denote that you're not sick. Let $+$ and $-$ denote positive and negative test, respectively. I think first I need to find $P(S|+)$, probability that you're sick given one positive test.

We know:
\begin{align}
    P(+|S) = 0.8 \\
    P(-|S) = 0.2 \\
    P(+|S^c) = 0.01 \\
    P(-|S^c) = 0.99 \\
\end{align}

According to Bayes rule, we have
$$
P(S|+) = \frac{P(+|S)P(S)}{P(+)}
$$

Then I think I can find the marginals using:
\begin{align}
    P(+) = P(+|S)P(S) + P(+|S^c)P(S^c) \\
    P(S) = P(S|+)P(+) + P(S|-)P(-) \\
\end{align}

Assuming this is the correct approach, and I find $P(S|+)$, how does this generalize to the case where there are 3 consecutive positive tests, i.e., how do I find $P(S|+,+,+)$?

Comment: You need to make some assumption regarding the independence of the test results. If, say, the test reports a false negative, is it more likely to report a false negative on the second try?

Comment: @lulu I think we assume independency between the trials.

Comment: So, in that case, what's the probability of a sick person getting three positive results?  What's the probability of a healthy person getting three positive results?

Comment: @lulu These are things I need to solve right, or are you asking for clarification?

Comment: I'm saying that independence gives you the answer to those.  Try an easier one:  what's the probability that a sick person gets two positive results?

Comment: @lulu If we assume independency, then I think the answer is $P(+,+|S) = P(+|S)*P(+|S)$?

Comment: So, what's the value in this case?

Comment: The idea here is that there are only two ways your patient might have gotten three positives.  Either they are sick and got three True Positives (A), or they are healthy and got three False Positives(B).  The answer you want is just $\frac {P(A)}{P(A)+P(B)}$

Comment: @ lulu Ah I see. So using my notation I am solving for $\frac{P(+++|S)}{P(+++|S) + P(+++|S^c)}$?

Comment: @lulu or is it $\frac{P(+++, S)}{P(+++, S) + P(+++, S^c)}$?

Comment: It's the latter.

Comment: @lulu Hmm I see. And that's equivalent to $P(S|+++)$? Ah yes, looksl ike that's just bayes

Comment: Just think of it intuitively.  $P(A)+P(B)$ is the probability of observing three positives.  Of that, $P(A)$ is the portion explained by being sick.  Hence the desired probability is just the ratio.

Comment: @lulu makes sense. I also realized the $p(++|S) = p(+|S)^2$ earlier is not necessarily correct. It would be correct if each positive test was conditionally independent, but we only know they’re marginally independent

Comment: We don't know anything at all about the independence...that's why I said you had to make assumptions.  Given the complete lack of information I expect you are meant to assume independence in all senses.  To be sure, that's not realistic.  My prior would be that False Positives (and False Negatives) were likely to be repeated, but there is no way to quantify that by guesswork, so I expect you are meant t just assume strong independence.

Comment: @lulu that’s a good point too. I’m not near a pen and paper right now but in my head I think if we don’t also assume conditional independence then we can’t get a numerical value for the solution.

Comment: Oh, you are right about that.  That's why I think you are meant to assume independence in all senses.  For a math problem, there's nothing wrong with that but it should be stated explicitly...I think people often get the idea that real world measurements like these are naturally independent but that isn't true.  If, say, a False Positive was caused by the presence of an antibody known to be associated with the disease (but which the patient possesses for some other reason) then you'd expect the test to find that antibody every single time.

Comment: @lulu. Under these assumptions, it seems the probability is essentially 1. I got that $P(A) = 0.0256$ and $P(B) = O(10^{-7}) \approx 0$.

Comment: Sorry, my last comment (now deleted) was an error. $P(B)=.95\times .01^3$ which is indeed very small.  So, yes.  I see the probability that you are sick, given that you got three positives to be $0.999962892$.  Not surprising since the test is very, very accurate for healthy people.

Answer (score 1):

Comment: You say correctly:

$$
P(S|+) = \frac{P(+|S)P(S)}{P(+)}\\
 P(+) = P(+|S)P(S) + P(+|S^c)P(S^c)
$$

And you give probabilities at the start that enable
you to find all the necessary probabilities, *including*
$P(S) = 0.05$ [and so $P(S^c) = 0.95]$ in your first sentence. So you can get $P(S|+),$ which you say you need.

Why does your last
displayed line try to compute $P(S)?$

I agree with @lulu that you will have to assume that tests are independent to finish this.